# How do I pass a DBNull value to a parameterized SELECT statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a SQL statement in C# (.NET Framework 4 running against SQL Server 2k8) that looks like this:

```
SELECT [Column1] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Column2] = @Column2
```

The above query works fine with the following ADO.NET code:

```
DbParameter parm = Factory.CreateDbParameter();
parm.Value = "SomeValue";
parm.ParameterName = "@Column2";
//etc...
```

This query returns zero rows, though, if I assign DBNull.Value to the DbParameter's Value member even if there are null values in Column2.  If I change the query to accommodate the null test specifically:

```
SELECT [Column1] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Column2] IS @Column2
```

I get an "Incorrect syntax near '@Column2'" exception at runtime.  Is there no way that I can use null or DBNull as a parameter in the WHERE clause of a SELECT statement?

Comment: remember null is not equal to null. try use LIKE instead of IS

Comment: One note. It is worth to set string fields as not null and not worry about such problems. Adding ORs or ISNULLs or COALESCE can really hit performance.

Comment: @LukLed - See the execution plan in my answer `OR` doesn't appear to cause a problem there. `WHERE [Column2] = @Column2 OR (@Column2 IS NULL AND [Column2] IS NULL) ` appears to be a recognised pattern and just end up with a straightforward index seek.

Comment: @Martin: You checked one specific case, but it is not always the same. Maybe it works fine here, but using functions is dangerous and Dan should be aware of it.

Comment: @LukLed - I agree which is why I went out of my way to check that the pattern in my answer was sargable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use

```
SELECT [Column1] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Column2] = ISNULL(@Column2 , 'value');
```

'value' can be any value that u want it to represent. If you want to match column2 that has null columns,

```
SELECT [Column1] FROM [Table1] WHERE ISNULL([Column2], 'value') = ISNULL(@Column2 , 'value');
```

Comment: This certainly works although I don't like how ugly my queries will have to get just to accommodate null values in parameters.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT [Column1] 
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE [Column2] = @Column2  OR (@Column2 IS NULL AND [Column2] IS NULL)
```

But I'm not sure how sargable this is.

Edit: This looks fine actually and ends up with an index seek at least in 2008

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1]
(
[Column1] INT,
[Column2] INT 
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX] ON [dbo].[Table1] ([Column2] ASC)

INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES(1,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES(2,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES(3,1)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES(4,1)
GO

CREATE PROC foo
@Column2 INT
AS
SELECT [Column1] 
FROM [Table1] 
WHERE [Column2] = @Column2  OR (@Column2 IS NULL AND [Column2] IS NULL)

GO

EXEC foo NULL
EXEC foo 1
```

[image: Plan]

Comment: +1 for all the checking, but I would still advise to create SQL dynamically, based on parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var cmd =new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL([Column1],'VALUE') as [Column1]  FROM [Table1] WHERE [Column2] = @Column2"),
                            con) 

string a;
if(textbox.text == string.empty)
{ a = DbNull.Value}
else { a =textbox.text}

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2",a);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

regards!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that they the values are NULL and not just empty strings? If it's the latter, it would indeed not return any record. And as Joel stated in his answer, yoou should allways change your `null` to `DbNull.Value` in your C#-code. If it's the first you should compare to `''` instead.

If the data is indeed NULL, maybe you can try this statement (if you're using stored procedures):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

SELECT [Column1] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Column2] = NULL
```

Take a look at the folowing [article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3399931/Working-With-Columns-That-Contain-Null-Values.htm) for some extra insight.

Answer (score -2):

Change your second line to this:

```
parm.Value = DbNull.Value;
```

That's all you have to do, really.  Don't worry about the `=` vs `IS` in this instance.

Where I'm at, our homegrown data access tier that we share among projects also checks all query parameters automatically and replaces any C# `null` with `DbNull.Value` before executing the query.

Comment: When I tried that, the query would always return zero rows even if there were NULL values in Column2.

Comment: Downvoted, because I tried this (connecting to MS SQL Server as well as SQLite) and it doesn't work. Got the same results as Dan.